# SQL Server : SELECT TOP 1 vs SELECT TOP 2 or more speed issue

Tags: sql-server

I am seeing vastly different query times on `SELECT TOP 1` vs changing the `TOP 1` to anything else like `TOP 2` or `TOP 10000`.

`TOP` anything > 1 runs in a millisecond, `TOP 1` runs in 12 minutes.

This is what the query looks like:

```
SELECT TOP ? 
    Column1, Column2, Column3,
    Column4, Column5, Column6,
    Column7,
    Column8 AS Column9,
    Column10, Column11,
    Column12 AS Column13,
    Column14,
    Object1.Column15 AS Column16,
    ? AS Column17,
    Column18
FROM
    Object2 Object1
INNER JOIN 
    CONTAINSTABLE(Object2, *, ?, ?) key_table ON Object1.Column19 = Object3.Column20
WHERE
    (Column6 IN (SELECT DISTINCT
                     Object4.Column21
                 FROM Object4
                 INNER JOIN Object5 ON Object4.Column22 = Object5.Column22
                 WHERE Object5.Column23 = ?
                   AND Object4.Column24 = ?))
ORDER BY 
    Column2 ASC;
```

AS you can see I am joining a full text query via `CONTAINSTABLE` on the tables PK. I am also checking that a resulting column is in a sub select. I have done the sub select in both the `IN ()` select, and changed it to a few more `INNER JOIN`. I show it this was because its the way the code is. It does the same thing either way.

The issue I have found is the execution plan. If I ask for the TOP 2 or more it will join on the WHERE column completely differently. You can see the difference in the query plans I have added in the Index Seek Object4.Index3. In top_issue_over_one there are only 2 seek predicates. In the top_issue_one there are 3, the third being the column from the sub select. When this happens it will have to loop the tables to get the data, there are potentially millions of records in each of these tables. You can also see from the plans the indexes that are there. They all have indexes on all columns.

To answer a few questions I will be asked proactively, yes the sort column is indexed and yes if I take it off it will run fast on both. Also, if I remove the full text query it will run fast on both. Its the combination of all of this that makes it happen.

I'm curious if anyone has seen this and has any idea why it is doing the plan differently on TOP 1 vs TOP anything else?

Comment: Are those *really* your table and column names? That should be a capital offense!

Comment: You can see the query plans here:
[sqlperformance.com](https://answers.sqlperformance.com/questions/3476/top-1-running-very-slow-vs-top-2-or-more-running-f.html)

Comment: looks like some statistics issue

Comment: Where does Object3 come from?  What is from FROM Object2 Object1?

Comment: @Frisbee the Object2 Object1 is just another example of completely absurd aliases in this query. I suspect (and really hope) these are fake names. I would shoot myself if I worked in an environment where those are real.

Comment: @SeanLange Object1 is an alias for Object2?  Both are referred to.  And were does Object3 come from?   Even fake names should be valid syntax.

Comment: Obviously they are not, that query has been anomylized through SQL Sentry.

Comment: Anomylized should be valid syntax.

Comment: It has been anonymized to the point that it is nearly impossible to decipher what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

According to the stages that are involved in the process of a Query the TOP represent a filter and is the last step, could you test another scenario where you change your query and put

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1
```

In place of TOP 1 and evaluate the difference, the other thing is try to apply

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Obviously in a dev environment.

Comment: I have tried SET ROWCOUNT 1, I should have said that, sorry. I have not tried killing the cache, I will bring the DB to my dev environment and try that.